# AFNetworking Queue Taking Long Time For First Request

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I have been using AFNetworking library for all of my Http Request , my sample request looks like this

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:requestObj];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id   responseObject) {

        [dic setValue:operation forKey:@"operationObj"];
        [dic setValue:responseObject forKey:@"jsonData"];

        [requestedView performSelector:callBackFunction withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] withObject:dic];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error resopnse => %@",error);

        [dic setValue:operation forKey:@"operationObj"];
        [dic setValue:error forKey:@"error"];

        [requestedView performSelector:callBackFunction withObject:[NSNumber   numberWithBool:YES] withObject:dic];
    }];
```

**When i make an Http Request for the First Time** the operational **queue is taking long time to start , sometimes i resulting in 0 as response status code**,

but once i try to **trigger the same request again** , i was not facing any issue.

am i missing something?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your request is but the completion and success blocks should affect the start time of the request. I normally use `AFJSONRequestOperation`s like this:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    // Success
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    // Failure
}];

[operation start];
```

Is there an `[operation start]` call under that we can't see?

Comment: ya i do have [operation start]; after the success and failure block, my problem is every first request is taking more time, some times request itself timed out

Comment: @Ramesh what server are you connecting to?

Comment: Google app engine , I don't think that it's server request is timed out

Comment: @Ramesh Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: Ya i did, but forgot to comment here, it was Google app engine front end instance issue, Google app engine will auto shutdown its front end instance if there is no request(for an particular time), so once a new request comes , it is taking time to start an new instance , that caused the delay.

its not an issue with afnetworking!!!

thanks for your interest in this post